# sudo make install didn't work for me, where are the installed files located

Tags: software-installation, make

I tried to compile a program from source. I should have all dependencies because the installation (or configuration or compilation) didn't show any errors. However, after installing the program, I can't find it in /bin folder, where it should supposedly be. I can't find it anywhere else either.

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. But I'm also a former Windows power user, so I can work with terminal no problem.

Anyone knows what could be the problem? Did I build the program wrong or did I install it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the program. What program did you try to install?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine It was a crypto currency wallet. Specifically Garlicoin Core. That's similar to Litecoin Core which is similar to Bitcoin Core. :P I tried to contact people in the Garlicoin forum and they say it should be in /bin folder.

Comment: Software that uses `autoconf` often defaults to installing in `/usr/local/bin` - see [GNU autoconf manual: 4.13 Default Prefix](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Default-Prefix.html)

Comment: @SurvivalMachine There are some files called Garlicoin in that folder (and I didn't put them there). So hopefully it's them. However, I don't know how to run them because they don't appear to have any extension. When I double click them, nothing happens. I can't see anything in processes either.

Comment: Run them in the terminal. cd into the directory and run `./Garlicoin` etc.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine It finally works! That's brilliant. But I have also one question. It'd be peculiar to always go to the terminal to run all of my "custom-build" programs. Can I write something like a "batch file" to run it for me? Also now I cant close the terminal because it'd terminate the application as well.

Comment: @ZuLeweiner Please [edit] your question to add the details from the comments. This helps keep the information together so the problem is clear. Glad you got it sorted, btw!

Comment: @ZuLeweiner For the "batch file", I think you want a .desktop launcher file. See [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/301745)

Comment: Thanks, @wjandrea. The launcher creation is a bit more difficult than I though. :D But now everything works! Awesome! I like Ubuntu. Thank you for help.